# How to compile .bib to LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I have been writing a manuscript using a .bib file and apacite, but the journal that I submitted to requires bibliography to be manually included within the .tex file like this

```
Johnson, A. \& Smith, B. (2014). Paper title. \textit{Journal Name, 101}(1), 111--123.
```

More specifically, right now my .tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
This is some previous work \cite{article1}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

ref.bib file looks like this:

```
@article{article1,
    Author = {Johnson, Adam},
    Journal = {Journal Name},
    Number = {101},
    Pages = {111--123},
    Title = {Paper title},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {2014}}
```

But the journal wants it to look something like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}
This is some previous work (Johnson, 2014).

\section*{Reference}
\begin{hangparas}{2em}{1}
Johnson, A. (2014). Paper title. \textit{Journal Name, 11}(101), 111-–123.
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

How can I convert the .tex file to the required format? Thanks.

Btw, the .bbl looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Johnson%
}{%
Johnson%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2014}}%
}]{%
article1}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
article1}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Johnson, A.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2014}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Paper title} {Paper title}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal Name}{11}{101}{111--123}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You use `pdflatex` `bibtex` `pdflatex` and `pdflatex`. Copy the contents of `yourfile.bbl` (generated by `bibtex`) finally at the end of your main file (i.e. `yourfile.tex`), send it to the publishers.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer --- MWE added now.

Comment: @HarishKumar The .bbl file looks like this, and I don't think this is what the editor wants.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Johnson%
}{%
Johnson%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2014}}%
}]{%
article1}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
article1}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Johnson, A.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2014}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Paper title} {Paper title}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal Name}{11}{101}{111--123}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\end{thebibliography}

Comment: @ceilingcat: Please add that `.bbl` content as a code block into your original post.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your created `.bbl` file without the `\begin|\end{thebibliography` into your document and define some apacity macros:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\renewcommand\bibitem[2][]{}
\def\citeauthoryear#1#2#3{}
\newenvironment{APACrefauthors}{}{}
\def\APACrefYearMonthDay#1#2#3{(#1)}
\def\APACinsertmetastar#1{}
\def\APACyear#1{}
\def\BBOQ{}\def\BBCQ{}
\def\newblock#1{#1}
\def\APACrefatitle#1#2{#1}
\def\APACjournalVolNumPages#1#2#3#4{\textit{#1, #2}(#3), #4}
\def\PrintBackRefs#1{}
\begin{document}
This is some previous work (Johnson, 2014).

\section*{Reference}
\begin{hangparas}{2em}{1}
\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {% 
  Johnson% 
}{% 
  Johnson% 
  }{%
   {\protect \APACyear {2014}}% 
   }]{% 
   article1} \APACinsertmetastar {% 
   article1}% 
   \begin{APACrefauthors}% 
   Johnson, A.% 
   \end{APACrefauthors}% 
   \unskip\ \newblock \APACrefYearMonthDay{2014}{}{}. \newblock {\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Paper title} {Paper title}.{\BBCQ} \newblock \APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal Name}{11}{101}{111--123}. \PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib} 
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it will be much more easier if you do *not* use the package `apacite`, then you do not have to redefine all that apa commands.

Comment: Is there a way to convert/compile `\cite{article1}` into `(Johnson, 2014)`, and `\citeA{article1}` into `Johnson (2014)`? There are a hundred or so of these cites and I try not to do it manually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sue, but that needs some redefinition of `\cite` which is the same as loading package `apacite` and using the `.bbl` file